# Prime ideals of the product of all countable integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let's gather up all the countable integral domains into a set $\vec{R}$ such that each countable integral domain appears exactly once up to isomorphism in $\vec{R}$. Let $\vec{R}$ be indexed by $I$.

Let's then define $A$ as $\prod_{i \in I} \vec{R}_i$.

We know from [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049867) that classifying the prime ideals of this object is probably hopeless, since even the simpler object $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ has really complicated prime ideals. I am curious, however, what prime ideals are lurking inside this object.

With that in mind, **what are some prime ideals of $A$?**

I have found one kind of prime ideals so far.

##### Ideals that are prime in exactly one component

Let $I$ be the product of $\vec{R}_i$ for all components of $\vec{R}$ but one and a prime ideal $J$ for the remaining component.

The complement of $I$ is isomorphic to the complement of $J$ and hence multiplicatively closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be much you can say. There is a surjective homomorphism $\vec{R} \to \prod_{d > 1} \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ and I bet that even that simpler product ring has no known prime ideal structure. See [SE/1533237](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533237/) for the already quite hard case $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$.

But since you have asked for examples. Let $(R_i)_{i \in I}$ be any family of integral domains. If $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter on the set $I$, then $\{a \in \prod_{i \in I} R_i : \{i : a(i)=0\} \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is a prime ideal in $\prod_{i \in I} R_i$. This applies in particular to your example where $I = $ all countable integral domains up to $\cong$ and $R_{i}=i$.